# Structure/Order of explaining distribution-theory

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, distribution-theory, fundamental-solution

please tell me if this is too off-topic, then I will delete the post. In my master thesis I want to use (and explain) distributions in order to solve some PDE, but since covid still is present it is hard for me to get academic feedback, so I thought maybe you guys can have a quick look and tell me whether the following structure is fine for introducing distributions. My global structure will be something like this:

- Introduction: PDEs are everywhere and solving them is hard
- Main part

  - PDEs
  - Distributions
  - Fourier Transforms
  - The Laplace Equation
  - The Wave Equation
  - A hypoelliptic operator of fourth order
- Conclusion: PDEs are still hard, but with distributions and fourier transforms specific problems can often be solved and surprising facts be derived

Now for Distributions I wanted to introduce it with "everything can be differentiated" and "Then for example the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) reduces to calculating the derivative of a characteristic function."
The structure should be like:

- **Derivative of the Heaviside function**

  - A first example.
  - There is no weak derivative for $\mathcal{H}$, but we want to have something like $\delta$.
- **Test functions**

  - There are functions in $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty$, for example the standard mollifier.
  - Also $lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \eta_\epsilon = \delta$
  - $\phi \mapsto \phi^{(k)}(0)$ should be a distribution, so there needs to be a topology on $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty$ that respects the derivatives.
  - $\mathcal{D}$ has the topology induced by $\sup_{x \in K} sup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n} \partial^\alpha \phi$.
  - This is not metrizable.
- **Definition of Distributions**

  - $\mathcal{D}'$ is the dual space of $\mathcal{D}$.
  - One can easier work with the usual definition of a linear map T with $|T(\phi) \leq C \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} sup_{x \in K} |\partial^\alpha \phi(x)|$.
  - Operators can be defined by its behaviour on test function, for example: $<\partial^\alpha T ,\phi> = <T , (-1)^\alpha \partial^\alpha \phi >$
  - Every distribution is the limit of a series of Testfunctions
- **Support of a Distribution**

  - One can define the support of a distribution
  - A distribution on $ X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$
  - We can restrict Distributions to a subset
  - Multiplication of Distributions
  - Definition of singsupp
- **Operators on Distributions**

  - The Tensor product
  - Convolution with a function
  - Convolution in general
- **Working with Distributions**

  - if $T' = 0$ then T is constant
  - calculating some derivatives
  - Complex Distributions
  - Calculating some limits
- **Fundamental solutions**

  - Definition
  - Application of $P (E_P * f) = f$ and $ u = E_P * (P u)$

I'm aware that this is somewhat unstructered. But this just reflects that I can't differ between technicalities and important theorems, apart from that fundemantal solutions are important for solving the inhomogeneous equation.

Thanks already and as I said, if it is too off-topic I will delete the question.

Comment: I'm not an expert on site rules re: off-topic, but it's a question to which you are unlikely to get useful responses. In particular, you are asking "Can have a quick look and tell me whether the following structure is fine." The criteria for what "is fine" will depend on your institutional guidelines, but probably almost anything at a sufficient level would work. Maybe try asking more specific questions about some of the math involved, if your actual goal is "this just reflects that I can't differ between technicalities and important theorems."

Comment: I guess you are right. The more I think about it, the more I see that there are several questions to which I have different levels of opinion. One is what are the main results when using distributions to solve differential equations. For this question I think one has to be specific which operator should be used. Another one is how and in which order can the basics best be explained, but here I also have to specify what the basics are. I will try to revise the question later this week, thanks. If there are hints/comments in the meantime, I am grateful :)